# React useEffect runs too often

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

### In short:

I have a side effect I want to happen when a value changes, but only if a second value is `true`. Since both values must be in the dependency array, the side effect is also triggered when the first value is unchanged and the second value is turned 'on', but I don't want it to.

### In detail:

I'm creating a game in React. I want to play (short) sound effects at various events, such as winning and losing. I have a simple helper function to play sounds, which works:

```
function playSound(url) {
  new Audio(url).play();
}
```

All the game logic is in a custom hook `useGame`. This hook returns, among other things, a click-handler for when the user makes a move (it handles updating all the relevant states in the hook) and a `winner` boolean (indicates whether the game is won).

I can't call `playSound` in the click-handler, because that closure only has access to the pre-click states and doesn't know if the game is won after the click. So I put it in a side-effect, with a dependency array to ensure it only happens once when the game is won.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (winner) {
    playSound(winSound);
  }, [winner]);
```

[Note: Internally, `winner` is stateless; it's calculated directly from the (stateful) board. So there are no `setWinner` calls I can tag along with.]

**This all works fine up to here**. But now I want to add a user setting to mute all sounds.

```
const [soundIsOn, setSoundIsOn] = useState(true);
```

Now I have to add this as a condition to calling `playSound` (or pass it as an argument to it).

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (winner && soundIsOn) {
    playSound(winSound);
  }, [winner, soundIsOn]);
```

Note that the the dependency array now needs to include `soundIsOn`. **The problem arises when** the sound is off, the user wins the game, and then the user turns sound on later. This effect will be called since `soundIsOn` changes, resulting in the win sound.

I've read through all the documentation and looked for similar questions. The only potential solution I've seen is to [use a ref inside a custom hook](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-get-previous-props-state-with-react-hooks/#:%7E:text=If%20you%E2%80%99re%20looking%20for%20an%20even%20quicker%20solution%2C%20you%20may%20abstract%20this%20functionality%20Into%20the%20custom%20Hook%20below%3A) to keep track of previous states and check which state has changed, but that seems a bit messy and unsatisfying. Is there a 'proper' way to deal with this type of thing? Ideally either by modifying the effect, or somehow working it into the click-handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution #1

Manage trigger event with other state not winner object itself.

```
const [winner, _setWinner] = useState(...);
const [shouldPlaySound, setShouldPlaySound] = useState(false);
// wrapper function (it is not required)
const setWinner = (winner) => {
   setShouldPlaySound(true);
   _setWinner(winner)
}
...
// if winner is selected
setWinner(...);
...
// Side effect
useEffect(() => {
   if(shouldPlaySound && soundIsOn){
       playSound(winSound);
   }
   setShouldPlaySound(false);
}, [shouldPlaySound, soundIsOn])
```

Also new `setWinner` wrapper function doesn't need to be defined with `useCallback` because it includes only `setState`s of `useState`.

But defining `setWinner` wrapper is not required. This is your choice for code readbility.

#### Solution #2

But I think if you need to play sound when winner is selected, just call `playSound` when winner is selected.

```
// when winner is selected
setWinner(winner);
if(soundIsOn){
  playSound(winSound);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much resolves my problem, though I had to make a few tweaks.

My ```winner``` isn't stateful, it's just a constant calculated from the (stateful) board. So solution #2 doesn't work for me since there are no ```setWinner``` calls to put the ```playSound``` call with. But solution #1 can work, I just have to replace the ```setWinner``` wrapper with another ```useEffect``` call instead (if ```winner``` changes value and is ```true```, call ```setShouldPlaySound```).

Comment: 2nd tweak: This is still a bit awkward since I need a different ```shouldPlaySound``` for each sound effect (winning, losing, draw, open game, etc.). So I replaced it with ```soundToPlay```, a stateful constant which holds the url of the sound (or is null). Now all sound effects can use this single common ```soundToPlay```.

Comment: @krmatthews great! anyway your problem was resolved. I will please to it